# Saving a View as a Photo in iPhone App

Tags: iphone

Is there an easy way to programmatically save a view to the Photos library in an iPhone app?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I added these methods to my view's controller class.  They save the photo and then pop up an alert box to tell the user whether it succeeded.

```
- (void)savePhotoOfView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);
    [view drawRect:view.bounds];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,
                                   self,
                                   @selector(savedPhotoImage:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                   NULL);
}

- (void)   savedPhotoImage:(UIImage *)image
  didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error
               contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{    
    NSString *message = @"This image has been saved to your Photos album";
    if (error) {
        message = [error localizedDescription];
    }
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                    message:message
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

Comment: This code is saving the white image (Blank image) into my Photo Alum can u please guide me what mistake i am making i have copy past the the above code into my project but not working :(

Comment: Maybe `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` just doesn't work with your view?